# How to recycle some magnetic disk of System on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, hard-drive

The system use 94GB disk. how to recycle some magnetic disk?

[image]

in there I can not click it.
my version is `10.14 (18A391)`.

Comment: By "recycle" do you mean recover as in recover some of that space for other storage?

Comment: yes, I want to left some space out, there always notifications from my Mac says there is no more space on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Your system storage space is more than usual.

Cache files can take up a lot of space.

How to remove them:

From [Mac Paw](https://macpaw.com/how-to/startup-disk-full-on-mac-os-x)

> Open a Finder window and select Go in the  menu bar.
>
> Click on “Go to Folder…”
>
> Type in `~/Library/Cache`s. Delete the files/ folders that are taking
>   up the most space.
>
> Now click on “Go to Folder…”
>
> Type in /Library/Caches (simply lose the ~  symbol) And, again, delete
>   the folders that  take up the most space.

Another thing that could help is starting in safe mode.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7683120)

> Try this...
>
> Start your mac in Safe mode by holding the shift key before the power
>   key
>
> Check your storage About This Mac/Storage etc. (In safe mode, mine
>   showed accurate usage)
>
> Restart in normal mode
>
> Repeat step #2.

Comment: All files or directories under this（`~/Library/Cache`） I can delete, right?

Comment: @aircraft yes you can

Answer (score 0):

I would look at moving some data or files onto separate storage.

There are also apps that will remove unused languages, duplicate files etc from the system if you want to look at those.

For duplicate files, looking in Apps, is "Duplicate Files Sweeper", (not used, just an example)

"Disk Cleaner" is an app that cleans all sorts, but it is not free... and not used by me either, so an example...